# Show that $(X,d)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space where $d$ is the discrete metric. That is:
$$\begin{equation}
d(x,y) =\left\{
   \begin{array}{@}
    0,\,\, if \,x = y,\\
1, \,\,if\, x \neq y.
   \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}$$

*I need to show that $(X,d)$ is complete (that every Cauchy-sequence in X converges to some point in X).*

What I've tried to do is this:

Pick an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ and suppose that it is Cauchy. That is, suppose that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $n_0$ such that $|x_n - x_m|< \epsilon$, whenever $m,n\geq n_0$. The fact that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy means that $(x_n)$ also converges to some point $x$, since for every $\epsilon >0$ we can find $n_0$ such that for $n \geq n_0$ we have that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$. I think that in my next step I should show that $x\in X$, but I don't really know how.

**Question:** How do I show that $(X,d)$ is complete? Or, if I'm on the right track: how do I show that $x \in (X,d)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is Cauchy, then there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$, we have that $d(x_n,x_m) <1/2$ for all $n,m>N$. Since the metric is discrete, this imposes that the sequence is constant after $N$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n,m\geq n_0$ we have $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$. In particular for $\epsilon=1/2$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$
$$d(x_n,x_m)<1/2$$
But since the distance can take values only $0$ and $1$, this means that for all $n,m\geq N$
$$d(x_n,x_m)=0.$$
Thus $(x_n)\rightarrow x_N$.